# Работа с двусвязными линейными списками

Tags: c++, visual-c++

Сформировать линейный список строк. Исключить из него последние три элемента. Скопировать в двусвязный циклический список вторую половину его элементов, начиная с конца. 
Список я сформировал, не могу понять как реализовать удаление последних трех элементов, и копирование в другой.

```
    #include <iostream>
using namespace std;
#include <locale.h>
struct node {
    int data;
    node* next;
    node* prev;
};



int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "rus");
    cout << "Введите количество элементов: ";
    int size;
    size = 0;
    cin >> size;

    node* head = NULL;
    node* tail = NULL;
    node* Curr = NULL;
    int i = 0;

    while (i < size)
    {

        Curr = new node;
        Curr->data = rand() % 100 + 1;
        Curr->prev = NULL;
        Curr->next = NULL;

        // Fill
        if (head == NULL)
            head = tail = Curr;
        else
        {
            tail->next = Curr;
            Curr->prev = tail;
            tail = Curr;
        }
        i++;
    }


    Curr = head;
    while (Curr)
    {
        std::cout << Curr->data << std::endl;
        Curr = Curr->next;
    }


    Curr = tail;
    while (Curr)
    {
        node* tmp = Curr;
        Curr = Curr->prev;
        delete tmp;
    }
    head = tail = NULL;

    return 0;
}
```